# Decrypt a PBKDF2 encrypted Session Key in PHP 7.2

Tags: encryption, php-7.2, pbkdf2

I need to upgrade a website I look after to PHP 7.2. In the testing phase i've discovered that one of the plug-in's on the site used the mcrypt library which is no longer available in PHP 7.2.

Essentially this plugin receives PBKDF2 encrypted data from a ticketing system (Tessitura) that returns the user's session key and a time stamp and an encrypted string.

In the control panel I have been given data to use to decrypt this session key such as a Passphrase, Salt, Authentication/HMAC Key , BlockSize, PaddingMode, EncryptionKeyIterations, EncryptionKeyLength and HMACLength

[Image of supplied fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eCNn.png)

I've been trying to work out how to decrypt the data but I confess i'm struggling. C

an anybody tell me how to use php 7.2 to achieve this? I've found some functions in the openssl suite that look like they may be the correct way to go but they all use different terminology to the information i've been given and I cannot work out where to start, what goes where or what settings to use

Thanks in advance to anybody that can solve this problem!!

Comment: PBKDF2 is not an encryption algorithm. It's a hashing algorithm. There (by design) is no efficient inverse function of a secure hash. The screenshot, however, looks like a block cipher (not PBKDF2). How to implement it depends entirely on the format, which is not explained in your screenshot. You'll need to consult the documentation. There is no way to guess what the format is.

Answer (score 0):

As Rob Napier said, PBKDF2 is what the system is using to hash the password being passed into the encryption process. The site is actually using aes-256-cbc encryption. That encryption process can include a password.

After the information is encrypted, that payload is signed with an HMAC key.

You can use the openSSL library to execute all of this in php 7 and higher. Here is some sample code that creates a class to handle the encryption/decryption, for example:

```
$crypto = new AesCryptoClass('YOUR_PASSPHRASE_HERE',
                        'YOUR_HMAC_KEY_HERE',
                        'YOUR_SALT_HERE');
class AesCryptoClass {

    // These should not change
    private $hmacLength = 32;
    private $iterations = 1000;
    private $keyLength = 32;
    private $blockSize = 16;
    private $cipher = 'aes-256-cbc';

    function __construct($password,$hmacKey,$salt)
        {
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->hmacKey  = $hmacKey;
            $this->salt     = $salt;
        }

    function encrypt($plainText)
        {
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16); 

            $encryptedBytes = $this->encryptInner($iv, $plainText);

            $encryptedMessage = $iv . $encryptedBytes;

            $mac = $this->hashMessage($encryptedMessage);

            $secureMessage = $mac . $encryptedMessage;

            $encryptedText = base64_encode($secureMessage);

            return $encryptedText;
        }

    function decrypt($encryptedText)
        {
            $secureMessage = base64_decode($encryptedText);

            $mac = substr($secureMessage, 0, $this->hmacLength);

            $encryptedMessage = substr($secureMessage, $this->hmacLength);

            $newMac = $this->hashMessage($encryptedMessage);

            if (strcmp($mac, $newMac) !== 0) {
                return "";
            }

            $iv = substr($encryptedMessage,0, $this->blockSize);

            $encryptedBytes = substr($encryptedMessage, $this->blockSize);

            $plainText = $this->decryptInner($iv, $encryptedBytes);

            return $plainText;
        }

    function encryptInner($iv, $plainText)
        {
            $encryptionKey = openssl_pbkdf2($this->password, $this->salt, $this->keyLength, $this->iterations);
            return openssl_encrypt($plainText, $this->cipher, $encryptionKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        }

    function decryptInner($iv, $encryptedBytes)
        {
            $encryptionKey = openssl_pbkdf2($this->password, $this->salt, $this->keyLength, $this->iterations);
            return openssl_decrypt($encryptedBytes, $this->cipher, $encryptionKey, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        }

    function hashMessage($encryptedMessage)
        {
            return pack("H*", hash_hmac("sha256", $encryptedMessage, $this->hmacKey));
        }
}
```

This code and the description of the process are also included here at the bottom of the wiki: 
https://bitbucket.org/TN_WebShare/webpro-session-sharing-sample/wiki/Session%20Key%20Encryption%20and%20Decryption